# Read a Bitbucket resource using curl with Access Keys

Tags: rest, curl, bitbucket

I configured my Bitbucket repo to be read-only accessible via REST API publicly. There are some JSON configuration files that I need to read the content using GET HTTP method.

```
https://<bitbucket-repo-url>/config.json?raw
```

I want to switch to a secure method using Access Keys.

[image]

I want to try to test this using curl, but I don't know the arguments on including the access keys. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Access keys are for SSH only. They will not work with any HTTP-based utilities (like curl) or endpoints (like the one you list in your example).

Is this Bitbucket Server (the on-premise version)? If so, https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/permanently-authenticating-with-git-repositories-776639846.html?_ga=2.188793826.854670382.1505151098-758028192.1431549295 may be helpful for you.